# Tool for checking Apex code formatting style

Tags: salesforce, apex, pmd

I want to find some tool for checking my Apex code for such things as tabs/spaces indents, braces position and so on.

Well, I've tried to implement such functionality using Checkstyle and PMD.
So, Checkstyle throws exceptions when meet syntax tokens different from Java (switch statement, string literals '').
With PMD I just didn't find any ways to resolve my issue using custom Java classes, there are just no properties to get information about indents in code.

I need a tool for using it via command line.

Comment: PMD can analyze Apex code, and ships some code style rules: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.18.0/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html but you may need to write your own rules / contribute them if you want anything not already shipped (ie: PMD's current rules can require braces, but doesn't enforce their position)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However there are no way I guess to check styles points such as indents (and whitespaces between statements and so on) as I mentioned above. I've already tried to write lots of custom rules but anyway I can't verify every case in styling

Comment: You can check for braces at least. All `BlockStatement` nodes have a `CurlyBrace` property to let you know if braces are in use or not, and you can check the `BeginLine` property to know if it matches the begin line of `IfBlockStatement` or not to know where the brace is located. Same applies to other flow control node types. Indentation may be a different problem with the current properties, but you can always ask for a feature in PMD's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite old but today if you'd need to check the code formatting, I think the best option is to use npm packages `prettier` and [`prettier-plugin-apex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-plugin-apex).

The `prettier-plugin-apex` is opinionated formatter, meaning there are not many options to adjust the code formatting. Due to that I forked it and added a couple of additional options as part of this package [`@ilyamatsuev/prettier-plugin-apex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ilyamatsuev/prettier-plugin-apex).